# Join multiple query result tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, postgis

I have two tables as following:

### table #1: graph

[image]

### table #2: junctions

[image]

What I want to do is to join both tables into one table. But not with the tables "directly", but rather with query result tables of the tables.

I have 3 query result tables which I want to join:

### query result table #1:

```
SELECT "from", st_x(st_pointn(geom,1)), st_y(st_pointn(geom,1))
FROM public.graph;
```

[image]

### query result table #2:

```
SELECT "to", st_x(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom))), st_y(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom)))
FROM public.graph;
```

[image]

### query result table #3:

```
SELECT id, priority
FROM public.junctions;
```

[image]

As I have written above, those 3 result query tables should now be joined to one table which should look like this:

[image]

Which basically means I want to join the first two result query tables, delete all duplicate entries and then join the third result query table so that every entry has a priority in addition.

How can I achieve this using SQL? Which joins do I need and how is the syntax when joining result table queries?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code, I have used cte to separate each result and in the end I have consolidate them in one query to display desired output. You can modify the JOIN condition or select columns that are required in the output.

```
WITH CTE_result1 AS
(
SELECT "from", st_x(st_pointn(geom,1)), st_y(st_pointn(geom,1))
FROM public.graph
),
CTE_result2 AS
(
SELECT "to", st_x(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom))), st_y(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom)))
FROM public.graph
),
CTE_result3 AS
(
SELECT id, priority
FROM public.junctions
)
SELECT
        CTE_result1.ID,
        CTE_result1.st_x    AS x,
        CTE_result1.st_y    AS Y,
        priority
FROM
        CTE_result1
    JOIN
        CTE_result2
            ON 'from' = 'To'
    JOIN
        CTE_result3
            ON ID = 'FROM'
               AND ID = 'To';
```

Comment: Hello auro, first of all, thank you very much for your answer. I have tried it out but I have come across an error when I execute the query. I says the column reference "st_x" is ambiguous (line 18 in the query). And I think it is because CTE_result1 and  CTE_result2 have the same columns (st_x and st_y). Do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: @user7335295 I have updated my answer. Can you try executing it now? When the column exists in both the tables, then we need to specify from what table we need to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

This query down below does the trick:

```
Select "from", st_x, st_y, priority from (SELECT "from" , st_x(st_pointn(geom,1)) , 
st_y(st_pointn(geom,1)) 
FROM public.graph
union
SELECT "to", st_x(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom))) , 
st_y(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom))) 
FROM public.graph
order by "from") as nodes  inner join
junctions on nodes."from" = id
```